# How to change site name font size for mobile device

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a website and when I view it on a mobile device it does not resize properly. I've managed to fix the page title size but I can't figure out how to change the site name size. I'm using word press free theme pinnacle. This is the css code I've used to adjust the page title

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

           h1 { font-size: 24px !important; }

         }
```

Comment: The code you've provided does not contain any information about your page's site name or the styles that affect it. Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont find a solution using css you can try using JS.

```
var element = document.getElementById("element");
element.style.fontSize = "//font-size";
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to find that. I'm very new to this. This is the source code from the page for the mobile screen
    div id="kad-shrinkheader" class="container" style="height:150px; line-height:150px;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-ss-10 clearfix kad-header-left">
        <div id="logo" class="logocase">
          <a class="brand logofont" style="height:150px; line-height:150px; display:block;" href="http://thefrolickingcanadian.com">
            The Frolicking Canadian          </a>

Comment: If The Frolicking Canadian is your page title, then target it with `.logofont`

Comment: just like I have in the code above then you would do var kad-shrinkheader = document.getElementById("kad-shrinkheader"); and then all you would have to do is say if(window.innerWidth < 850){ kad-shrinkheader.style.fontSize = "//Some font size}  To explain that code its gettings the element by its Id and naming it "kad-shrinkheader" . The the code check the windows width and if its less than 850 it will make kad-shrinkheader a certain size.